# how to use foreman query in puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have foreman query, which get puppet nodes from Foreman hostgroup.
I want use output from this query in my puppet manifest in nodes section.

My foreman query:

```
$query = foreman({foreman_user => 'admin',
                  foreman_pass => 'pass',
                  item         => 'hosts',
                  search       => 'hostgroup_fullname ~ web servers',
filter_result => ['certname'],
})
```

I want use  "${_query}" variable in nodes class

Something like this:

```
node "${_query}" {

file { '/tmp/testdir':
    ensure => 'directory',
  }

file { '/tmp/testdir/testfile2':
  ensure => present,
  content => 'this is test file in directory',
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root'
    }

}
```

In normal Puppet manifest I must use this multiple nodes sintax:

```
node 'www1.example.com', 'www2.example.com', 'www3.example.com' {
file { '/tmp/testdir':
    ensure => 'directory',
  }

file { '/tmp/testdir/testfile2':
  ensure => present,
  content => 'this is test file in directory',
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root'
    }
}
```

When I execute my manifest with my foreman query I got this error:

```
Server Error: Could not parse for environment production: An interpolated expression is not allowed in a hostname of a node
```

I Understand the problem is in my foreman query variable.

How I must change my foreman query to use in myltiple nodes section in my manifest file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message says to not interpolate an expression in the node definition name, so try that. It can be easily done with `node $query`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Foreman host groups with Puppet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655473/how-can-i-use-foreman-host-groups-with-puppet)

Comment: I'm afraid you hit a foul ball there, @MattSchuchard, prompting [the OP's next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655473/how-can-i-use-foreman-host-groups-with-puppet).  The fact is, I can't think of any reason why it would be useful to use a variable in or as a node name at all, and indeed Puppet does not support it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To be honest I did not scrutinize the question as much as you. I just saw some code, a straightforward error message, and made the obvious suggestion. Indeed, upon further scrutiny, the problem here is deeper.